# Accessing functions for a minor-mode from another file

Tags: minor-mode

Have made two files, the first (`komis.el`) has the definition of the minor-mode (`komis-minor-mode`), whereas the second file (`komis-luna.el`) contains some additional functionalities that should be available to the minor-mode.

How can I access the functions in `komis-luna.el` to `komis.el`.

Comment: The same way that you access functions from any file in any other file: you use `load-file`, `load-library`, or `require`. The docs explain it all and there are thousands of examples in the Emacs lisp code. Please read the docs and stop asking the same questions over and over.

Comment: I have used `require` which solved the problem.  My capabilities are improving, which should cater to your request.

Comment: My request has always been that you do some research before you ask a question. Instead of asking questions a few times a day, you should work on a problem for a while, read the docs, search the web, try some things on your own, see where they break, think about it and try to fix the problems you encounter, and strive to reduce the frequency of your questions to, say, one a week: that will force you to try to figure it out on your own and that will improve the quality of your questions.

Comment: And the other thing I sak you is to *stop* the silly game of hiding behind new identities: choose one and stick to it.

Comment: @Pampalula if you have found the answer to your problem, please post it as an answer and accept it, so that stackoverflow can grow and become more useful over time to the people who come after you.